# Get latest version of application on reload using Angular 5 & Service Worker

Tags: angular, angular5, service-worker, angular-service-worker

I am using Angular 5 with service worker for one of my application. Service worker is working fine as expected but I am not able to use SwUpdate functionality of service worker. I am using below code in my app component to check for update-

```
import { SwUpdate } from '@angular/service-worker';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private swUpdate: SwUpdate) { }
  ngOninit() {
    this.swUpdate.available.subscribe(event => {
      console.log('A newer version is now available. Refresh the page now to update the cache');
    });
    this.swUpdate.checkForUpdate()
  }
}
```

When I am checking my application on server, it always gives error as below -
[image]

Comment: Are you sure, this error is from Service Worker? I don't think so

Comment: Yes. Whenever I create a reference of SwUpdate in constructor, i get this error.

Comment: As far I know, (I have done onetime) the service worker update works automatically.

Comment: Doesnt looks like service worker issue. Even if it is, you have to post detailed error message. From the screenshot, its not clear what is missing/causing the error.

Comment: Ok..I will try to put detailed error message here.

Comment: as per screenshot, i don't think so its service worker error.